# Is possible to access net.tcp service(WCF) through java client?

Tags: java, web-services, wcf

A net.tcp service can only be reached by .net aplication? or i can acess then through java client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, only by .Net applications. NetTcpBinding do not conform to any public protocol, so it is limited to communication between .Net components and is optimzed for WCF. Net.tcp is specific to Microsoft .NET framework and uses .NET binary as message encoding. 
Other simple http bindings conforms to the WS-I Basic Profile 1.1, so they can be used to interact with components with other languages.

Please refer to this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2dd96345-e822-4922-83f6-3a875613ee49/nettcpbinding-and-java-web-services?forum=wcf)

Comment: one more thing... how can i check if the service is really NetTcpBinding?